# How to convert number to string in array of object

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to convert number values to string
I have array of object like

```
Var data = [{ name : "car1" , price : 255,  item : 100}, { name: "car2", price : 1800 , item : 155} ........]
```

I am trying to convert number to string
And data should look like

```
Var  data  = [{ name : "car1" , price : "255",  item : "100"}, { name: "car2", price : "1800" , item : "155"} ........]
```

I know how to do for a single value but no idea for multiple values, any idea on how to convert?

Answer (score 2):

Use below logic to convert number to string

```
let num = 15;
let text = num.toString();
```

To do this for multiple objects in an array use forEach to loop over the array

```
data.forEach((element)=>{
 element.price = element.price.toString();
 element.item = element.item.toString();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert all of the values at once with a nested loop:

```
data = data.map((row) => // for each row
  Object.fromEntries( // Convert array back to map after next line
    // Convert object to an array of arrays with key-value pairs
    Object.entries(row).map(
      // `${value}` is a template string, thus auto-converting all props to strings.
      ([key, value]) => [key, `${value}`]
    )
  )
);
```

Or, you can use a for loop:

```
data.forEach((row) => {
  for (const key in row) {
    row[key] = `${row[key]}`;
  }
});
```

There's lots of other ways to do this as well.